# Losing intellisense for MongoDB? VSCode

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm learning MongoDB and I keep hitting a strange issue I can't get my head around, here is my code:

```
// === MODULES
const routes = require('express').Router();
require('dotenv').config();

// === MONGODB
const { connectMongo } = require('../mongodb');

// === CONSTANTS
const mongoDB = process.env.MONGO_DB_NAME;

// === ROUTES
// GET: Returns a list of 'Clients' contained within MongoDB Client Collection
routes.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // Acquire our Connection
    const connection = await connectMongo();
    // Select the Database
    // TODO: .env the MongoDB Database Name
    const db = await connection.db(mongoDB);
    // Find our Collection
    const collection = await db.collection('clients');
    // Grab our Clients and map to an array
    const clients = await collection.find({}).toArray();
    // Close our connection
    await connection.close();

    // Send the client data
    res.send(clients);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});

// POST: Adds a new Client to the Clients collection
routes.post('/add', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // Client should be posted from a form, which is exposed on req.body through bodyParser
    const client = req.body;

    if (!client) {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: 'No client was specified',
      });
    }

    const connection = await connectMongo();
    const db = await connection.db(mongoDB);
    const collection = await db.

    res.send(client);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});

// === EXPORT
module.exports = routes;
```

In the 'GET' route, the intellisense works as I expect, e.g. at the:

```
await connection.close();
```

I get the intellisense for the .close();

However, in the POST route, the intellisense only works as far as the:

```
const db = await connection.db(mongoDB);
```

See screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of Intellisense]

Comment: Did you install the types for the mongo db package?

Comment: I thought I only needed to use types if I'm using TypeScript? Which I'm not at the moment. Also, it seems to work and then stop working randomly. Now the GET route also does not have intellisense if I go back over it now. It also stops at the const db = await connection.db(mongoDB); line

Comment: No, for intellisense to work you need the types installed :(

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. But the intellisense works fine until half way down the page. It also works fine if I create the connection within this file. My understanding is types are for TypeScript as mentioned. Intellisense has always worked for me without installing types. For example, all express intellisense works, and I haven't installed types for that.

Comment: Unless the package ships with types or you roll your own you need to install.

Comment: Okay, so I'm guessing both Mongo and Express ship with their own types, as the intellisense works. What I'm struggling to understand is why the intellisense stops half way down my file. As I've said, intellisense works absolutely fine until I get to the particular line I've highlighted. If it works up until that point its safe to assume its not that I need to install the types. If you read the question, I explain that intellisense works, until I get to the const db = await connection.db(mongoDB); in the POST route.